# jqgrid inline editing triggering successfunc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, grid

I am using *jqgrid* for inline editing.

Following is code snippet for enabling the last row of grid for editing and adding parameters to it.

```
gridComplete: function ()
{
    var lastrowid = jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
    var se = "<input type='button' value='Save' onclick=\"jQuery('#list10').saveRow('"+lastrowid+"');\" />"; 
    var parameters = {
            height: 30,
            act:se,
            keys : false,
            restoreAfterError : false,
            mtype : "POST",
            editParams:{
                successfunc:function(response) {
                alert("success");
                FLAG = true;
                return true;
                }
            },
            errorfunc: function(rowid, res) {
                $.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap, res.responseText , $.jgrid.edit.bClose, {top:400,left:565});
            }
    };
    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('editRow',lastrowid,parameters);
    jQuery("#list10").setSelection(lastrowid);
    $('#list10 tr:last').focus();
    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('setRowData',lastrowid, parameters);
    jQuery("#list10").trigger('reloadGrid');            
},
```

I want to trigger `successfunc` for setting a flag, so I have written the code there, but it is not executing(not showing alert), so is there anything wrong in code?

Any help will be appreciated.